# Error 1093 when trying to perform delete in MySQL

Tags: mysql

A little help with this query please. When trying to perform a delete in MySQL, it returns an error: "MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause". The select statement works fine otherwise. Here's the script:

```
DELETE
  FROM redcap_data
WHERE record IN (SELECT DISTINCT
  redcap_data.record,
  redcap_data.field_name,
  redcap_data.value
FROM redcap_metadata
  INNER JOIN redcap_data
    ON redcap_metadata.project_id = redcap_data.project_id
  INNER JOIN redcap_events_metadata
    ON redcap_data.event_id = redcap_events_metadata.event_id
  INNER JOIN redcap_events_arms
    ON redcap_events_metadata.arm_id = redcap_events_arms.arm_id
WHERE (redcap_data.project_id = '50'
AND redcap_events_arms.arm_num = '6'
AND redcap_data.record IN ('record_ids go here')
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an inner join on the subselect you are using as IN clause instead of the IN clause

```
    DELETE r.*
      FROM redcap_data r
    INNER JOIN  (
      SELECT DISTINCT
      redcap_data.record,
      redcap_data.field_name,
      redcap_data.value
    FROM redcap_metadata
      INNER JOIN redcap_data
        ON redcap_metadata.project_id = redcap_data.project_id
      INNER JOIN redcap_events_metadata
        ON redcap_data.event_id = redcap_events_metadata.event_id
      INNER JOIN redcap_events_arms
        ON redcap_events_metadata.arm_id = redcap_events_arms.arm_id
    WHERE (redcap_data.project_id = '50'
    AND redcap_events_arms.arm_num = '6'
    AND redcap_data.record IN ('record_ids go here')
    )) t ON r.record = t.record
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r
    INNER JOIN  (
      SELECT DISTINCT
      redcap_data.record,
      re' at line 2

Comment: Unexpected symbol 'r' Unexpected symbol 't'

Comment: what do you mean with the last  comment  .. is a part of the error message?

Comment: Yes. I reformatted the script and that's the error I received.

Comment: anyway  .. r removed

Comment: t  .. is the table name alias for subquery  .. +

Comment: which db your are using  ?? try test the code  in a sql ide or sql console  ..could be is a problem with your reformat ..

Comment: Im using dbForge Studio for MySQL accessing MySQL 5.6.12. I'm not using the reformatted version.

Comment: please .. updated your question and add  your actual code ..  anyway answer updated .  with r.*

Answer (score 0):

It's a documented restriction in MySQL.

One workaround is to use an inline view (derived table), and reference that in a JOIN operation.

Write it as SELECT first

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM target_table t
  JOIN ( SELECT q.id
           FROM target_table q 
           JOIN ... r
             ON ...
          WHERE ... 
          GROUP BY ... 
         HAVING ...
       ) s
    ON s.id = t.id
```

Then we can convert that to a DELETE statement. In my experience, the inline view gives enough separation of target_table in the outer query, that it doesn't raise the MySQL error.

At the time the outer query runs, the query that materializes derived table `s` has already been executed. The operations that MySQL performs is akin to this  (not exactly this, but this illustrates the pattern, how we can think about the derived table ...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _s_ ... ;
INSERT INTO _s_ (...) SELECT ... FROM target_table q ... ;

DELETE t.*
  FROM target_table t
  JOIN _s_ 
    ON ... 
;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE _s_ ... ;
```

At the time the DELETE statement runs, it doesn't matter that `target_table` is referenced in the preceding SELECT.  The work to materialize the temporary table *s* has already been done.